# Problem books on harmonic analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, book-recommendation, harmonic-analysis

I just got a copy of the book **A Course In Abstract Harmonic Analysis by Gerald B Folland** so I want a **problem book** that could be used with it?

> Please give a list of problem books on Harmonic Analysis?

Answer (score 2):

An Intro to Harmonic Analysis by Yitzhak Katznelson has exercises following each chapter. It is easy to draw parallels between books for content like this.

Harmonic Analysis by Henry Helson is in the same boat. There are about 5 problems after each chapter’s section.

Lastly, Barry Simon’s book “Harmonic Analysis: A comprehensive course in Analysis” also contains various problems at the end of each significant subsection.

Good luck, and I hope this serves your studying well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful book for your case:

A A Kirillov, A D Gvishiani
Theorems and Problems in Functional Analysis.